# how to visualize data from mysql database in force layout of d3 tool

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I need some help with d3 and MySQL. Below is my question:

I am using d3 force directed layout to visualize data stored in MySQL. I now want to visualize it using d3. As far as my knowledge of d3 goes, it requires json file as input that contain nodes and links. My question is: How do I access this MySQL database from d3 script  in specified format? I want this kind of input for d3 tool. Please help me.

```
   {"nodes":[{"name":"Myriel","group":1},
           {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
                                                                                                              {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":1}],
      "links":[{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
         {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
          {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a blog post here on using a MySQL database with D3 http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html.

The key is to have the call for data in d3 call a php script that returns the data in a format that d3 expects.

For instance this line;...

```
d3.json("php/data2.php", function(error, data) {
```

... is is telling d3 to get data in a JSON format, but it's calling a php script that is doing the querying of the database and returning the data in JSON format;

Here's the script (data2.php) that its calling;

```
<?php
    $username = "homedbuser"; 
    $password = "homedbuser";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="homedb";

    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "
SELECT  `date`, `close` FROM  `data2`
";
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $myquery ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);     

    mysql_close($server);
?>
```

Comment: thnx.. i just want to know that will json_encode will return me the data in required format that i have mentioned above. please help

Comment: thnx a lot d3noob, i m able to convert my data into json format. but i am not able to call that php script from my d3 code. can any one help me to call this script from d3 code.

Comment: Do you have php installed? (if you are using WAMP that would be yes, but if you are just running the html file locally that would be preventing you using the php script). To test this, you can point your browser at the php file and it should echo the data to the browser directly.

Comment: @d3noob isn't this solution going to fall short if there are isolated nodes?

Comment: @user299791 - Good question. I concentrated on trying to answer the question of gathering the data from a MySQL database (Which I *think* it does). The best way to know for certain if there is a limitation is to try a test. Please bear in mind that the above code is a bit historical and a PDO or MySQLi call should probably be used instead (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).